# iOS - play a song from iTunes which the user has not purchased?

Tags: ios, itunes

I have not started coding my app but I have an idea and want to see if this part of it is possible. Would it be ok if, given a track ID, I played the song (through MediaPlayer) in the app, even if the user had not bought the song and do not have it in their library?

If not, what would be the best way to play music that anyone (or most people, at least) can listen to as they use my app?

Comment: I'm sure that artists who sell their music through iTunes would certainly hope that this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can play music that:

- is in the user's library
- or, is embedded in your app
- or, is available online where your app can readily access it (assuming reachability etc.)